# How do I unpivot this multiple header and variable data table?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a lab report in excel which contain multiple level of header and multiple variables as well,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsJcr.png)

I'd like to unpivot it to a flat table with pandas into the format shown as in the picture below, can someone help?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LZje.png)

Comment: Don't use images, instead add code that creates a sample of your input dataframe.  [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read it into a dataframe, see exactly how in this answer:
[reading excel sheet as multiindex dataframe through pd.read_excel()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35300099/reading-excel-sheet-as-multiindex-dataframe-through-pd-read-excel)

And then stack your dataframe with `df.stack()`.