# Rename columns of excel using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am learning pandas for data cleaning. I am reading one excel file like below.

[image: Excel Image]

What I am looking to do is to rename column names like, *`First Cost Q3 2020, First Cost Q4 2020, First Cost Q1 2021`* and so on. There are other column names **"AUFC", "First Cost Growth %"** and many more. And I also have to make the same like "First Cost".

I am new to pandas and not getting idea How can I rename columns like this. Can any one guide me?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [tour] and [mre] and in this case also: [how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: hi! Is any one of the answers below working? If so & if you wish, you might consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) one of them to signal others that the issue is resolved. If not, you can provide feedback so they can be improved (or removed altogether)

Answer (score 2):

You can rename a column name by using:

`df.rename(columns = {'Q3 2020':'First Cost Q3 2020'}, inplace = True)`

To update all column names, you can do this:

`df.columns = ['First Cost Q3 2020', 'First Cost Q4 2020', 'First Cost Q1 2021']`

Answer (score 1):

Try via `columns` attribute and `map()` method:

```
df.columns=df.columns.map(' '.join)
```

Now If you print `df` or `df.columns` you will get your expected output

Answer (score 0):

Simpliest way is to assign the list of desired column names as below (it must be all columns):

```
df.columns = ['First Cost Q3 2020', 'First Cost Q4 2020', etc].
```

If Pandas reads this excel as a multilevel columns you will need some more work. Let us know if this is the case

Comment: Yes, they are multilevel columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the excel file with multiindex columns by adding parameter `header=[0,1]` as follows (described better [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35300099/reading-excel-sheet-as-multiindex-dataframe-through-pd-read-excel)):

```py
df = pd.read_excel(your_path, 
                   header=[0,1], 
                   sheetname=your_sheet_name)
```

And then later merge the multiindex as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24290297/pandas-dataframe-with-multiindex-column-merge-levels):

```py
df.columns = df.columns.map(' '.join).str.strip(' ')
```